# Custom URL for toast notification buttons in registry

Tags: powershell, cmd

I trying to run a command that opens up Software Center on my machine. It works just fine if I run it in Command Prompt but not when I call it from my custom protocol handler in the registry. The main problem is that when called from the protocol handler, via a Toast button, Windows tells me I need a new app to open this.

Here is the command.

```
"C:\WINDOWS\CCM\ClientUX\SCClient.exe" softwarecenter:Page=Applications FilterType=0 SortType=6 View=Upcoming
```

Here is how I am setting up the protocol handler in registry

```
New-item 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ToastSoftwareCenter' -force
Set-itemproperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ToastSoftwareCenter' -name '(DEFAULT)' -value 'url:ToastSoftwareCenter' -force
Set-itemproperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ToastSoftwareCenter' -name 'URL Protocol' -value '' -force
New-itemproperty -path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ToastSoftwareCenter' -propertytype dword -name 'EditFlags' -value 2162688
New-item 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ToastSoftwareCenter\Shell\Open\command' -force
Set-itemproperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ToastSoftwareCenter\Shell\Open\command' -name '(DEFAULT)' -value '"C:\WINDOWS\CCM\ClientUX\SCClient.exe" softwarecenter:Page=InstallationStatus FilterType=0 SortType=6 View=Upcoming' -force
```

I have tried appending these other commands on the end of the command to associate it as an exe so it wont ask anymore, but to no avail.

```
ftype exefile="%1" %*

assoc .exe=exefile\
```

The commands work when running them from a command prompt but not from the protocol handler. Am I setting it up wrong?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating the protocol in the wrong location. It needs to be created under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`

You also need to create the PSDrive in order to easily access that location within PowerShell.

```
New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT -Name HKCR
New-Item 'HKCR:\ToastSoftwareCenter' -Force
```

[Registering the Application Handling the Custom URI Scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#registering-the-application-handling-the-custom-uri-scheme)

Comment: I have placed it in HKCR with the PSDrive but It still asks what app I would like to open a CMD command with.

Comment: Nevermind, got it working, had it in HKCR:\SOFTWARE still. Thank you!